# getting last word in a tokenized string in groovy

Tags: string, groovy

A basic String handling question..I have a tokenized String like val1.val2.val3.....valN
How do I get the last word valN from the string above.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you pass a negative index n to the [subscript operator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#getAt%28int%29) in a List, you get n-th last element. Therefore, the -1 element is the last one:

```
def words = 'val1.val2.val3'
def last = words.tokenize('.')[-1]
assert last == 'val3'
```

**Update**: You also have the, arguably more readable, [`last`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#last%28%29) method:

```
def last = words.tokenize('.').last()
```

Comment: how can you use `.last()` to replace this: `words.tokenize('.')[-2]` ?

Comment: @A.Man, last() only returns the last element, and there's no method to get the second-to-last i think. You could do array.dropRight(1).last() i guess, but at that point accessing array[-2] is much more readable in my opinion.