# How to get commitHash from windows slave

Tags: windows, cmd, jenkins-pipeline, git-commit

So far I used the below code for getting the `commitHash` in my `JenkinsFile.groovy` from linux slaves:

```
def commitHash = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git rev-parse HEAD").trim()
```

Now I'm running on `windows` slave. How can I modify this command to run on `windows` as well through `CMD`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very same command should work with a [`bat` step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#bat-windows-batch-script)

```
def commitHash = bat(returnStdout: true, script: "git rev-parse HEAD").trim()
```

You only need to make sure `git.exe` is in the agent `%PATH%`.

You can have a dedicated pipeline for 'Windows' [agents](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2020/05/06/docker-agent-image-renaming/) (agents with the label 'Windows') in order to execute those OS-specific steps orchestrated by the [controller](https://groups.google.com/u/0/g/jenkinsci-dev/c/CLR55wMZwZ8/m/AdMfXV-wAgAJ).

Comment: BTW, I get this answer: `c:\jenkins-slave\workspace\test-K5I54FOWDXJU7QWEX2YF4ZSWVNSFITDVMLAIK3SVMG3V4JJM2QHA>git rev-parse HEAD  1234` how can I take only `1234`?

Comment: @arielma I would suppose by processing the string you get, in order to get only the last word. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11726873/6309)

Comment: it's `windows` command, I need `groovy` command for doing it

Comment: @arielma OK: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9660850/6309

Comment: I tried it, but now working for my case. I tried to debug it here: `https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-groovy-online/`. anyway I've open new question for this issue...

Comment: @arielma Good idea: a separate question will be better addressed.

Comment: I know it's not related to the question, but can you tell me the commands for `git tag` in windows slave (using `hash`)? Is it the same as in Linux machine?

Comment: @arielma It should be the very same. Let me know what exact command you are using and if you see any error as a result.